# Laravel 5.2 - Delete from db

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `Laravel Framework version 5.2.45`.

I have created a simple view that outputs my todos:

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
    {{ $todo->todo }} <button href="{{ route('todo.delete', ['id' => $todo->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger">x</button>

    <hr>
@endforeach
```

Within my routes I have created the following route to delete a `todo`:

```
Route::get('/todo/delete/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'TodosController@delete',
    'as' => 'todo.delete'
]);
```

Within my `TodosController` I created the following `delete` method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Todo;

class TodosController extends Controller
{

    public function delete($id) {
        $todo = Todo::find($id);

        $todo->delete();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
// ...
```

When I press the button in the frontend nothing happens. I do not get any error...

Any suggestions what is wrong with my implementation?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: try `dd($id)` inside your controller function and check if the request reach there

Comment: @ShobiPP No, when I press the button nothing happens...

Comment: To use buttons for navigation you may need to use a form or JavaScript. Otherwise you can change `<button>` to `<a>`

Comment: Please mark the solution answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are using button not tag**

turn your code from

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
   {{ $todo->todo }} <button href="{{ route('todo.delete', ['id' => $todo->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger">x</button>
   <hr>
@endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
   {{ $todo->todo }} <a href="{{ route('todo.delete', ['id' => $todo->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger">x</a>
   <hr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Below code, You have used a button instead of a tag

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
            {{ $todo->todo }} <a href="{{ route('todo.delete', ['id' => $todo->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger">x</a>

            <hr>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this :

Delete Button :

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('todo.delete',$todo->id) }}">Delete</a>
```

And delete function look like below :

```
public function delete($id) {
    try {
        $delete_flag = Todo::where(['id' => $id])->first();
        $delete_flag->delete();
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Todo deleted successfully');
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Something went wrong');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
   {{ $todo->todo }} <a href="{{ route('todo.delete', ['id' => $todo->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger">x</a>

@endforeach

delete code--
$toDo = Todo::findOrFail($id)->delete();
if($toDo){
   return response()->josn(['message'=>'deleted']);
}
```